# add product prestashop webservice. So difficult?

Tags: web-services, prestashop-1.5

I'm searching for a tutorial or documentation where is explained the webservice use of Prestashop (v1.5.6.0).
I'd like simply add or edit (update) o product.
There is'not a tutorial clean or with example about use of prestashop's api.
Coul you help me please ?

For example, i'd like add object a:

```
define('PS_SHOP_PATH', 'http://localhost/myshop'); // Root path of your PrestaShop store                        
define('PS_WS_AUTH_KEY', '****'); // Auth key (Get it in your Back Office)
require_once('api/PSWebServiceLibrary.php');

$webService = new PrestaShopWebservice(PS_SHOP_PATH, PS_WS_AUTH_KEY, DEBUG);
$opt = array('resource' => 'products');
```

Now, how can i set my values for a new object ? In the example you can insert only required value.
Could you help me ?

And for update ?

Please ,no linked me Prestashop documentation, i have already read it, i'm asking your help.
Thanks and excuse for my bad english.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the [link](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Using+the+PrestaShop+Web+Service) to the official documentation. You will find there all the information you need.

Basically, you'll need to create an XML that represents the object you'd like to PUT.

Lets say you want to create a new category.

First, you need to get the schema :

```
$xml = $webService->get(array('url' => PS_SHOP_PATH.'/api/categories?schema=blank'));
```

Which is something like this :

```
<prestashop>
    <category>
    </category>
</prestashop>
```

Then you'll have to set the content of the xml ($resources)

```
$resources = $xml->children()->children();
$resources->active = true;
$resources->..........
etc.
```

Finally,

```
try 
{
    $opt = array('resource' => 'categories');
    $opt['postXml'] = $xml->asXML();
    $xml = $webService->add($opt);
} 
catch (PrestaShopWebserviceException $e) 
{
    echo 'Something went wrong: '.$e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks, perfect. I create my product, and works. Two little question: 1. why in backend in product tabs doesn't show the category of appartenence ? If i click on product the category is checked and correct. 2. I'd like that a product in database become an attribute of another product. For example two product in database, with two id and two reference code that are same, identical but with different color, o different size. Is it possibile combine them ? How ?

Thanks

Comment: You are welcome! Please post an other question wit your code and be as precise as possible about the issues (include screenshots if necessary). In the mean time I suggest you remove your latest answer to this question as it violates stackoverflow's terms. If my answer solved your primary issue, consider marking it as "accepted" so that the community can benefit from it.